# How to open a PDF file without any package?

Tags: r, pdf

Im trying to open a pdf file which is my working directory. here is code

```
shell.exec("abc.pdf")
```

This is the error i get.
    Error in shell.exec("abc.pdf") : 
    file association for 'abc.pdf' not available or invalid

Also i tried opening it through system command, but doesn't work.

```
system2("open abc.pdf")
```

This is the error i get.
    Warning message:
    running command '"open abc.pdf"' had status 127

Do i have to assign a default pdf reader for the same.

Comment: Have you looked at `?file.show`

Comment: As `?shell.exec` says, it "Opens the specified file or URL using the application specified in the Windows file associations.". You could also use something like `system('"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Adobe\\Reader\\AcroRd32.exe" C:\\Users\\Username\\Documents\\mypdf.pdf')`.

Comment: @Benjamin file.show give the top most error.

Comment: @lukeA: this worked.......the codes too long. is there a work around for this. like setting acrobat as a default reader or something.

Comment: @lukeA  how do i set a default pdf reader. i think sumatra is the default for r studio. and i don't have that.

Comment: In an interactive session (i.e. not scripting), I personally go with `shell.exec`. I have associated the pdf extension with the adobe acrobat reader on Windows. It seems, you don't have any file association on your Windows - or it's broken.

Comment: shell.exec is opening the pdf now. i checked for file association for pdf, it was acrobat reader only in my windows setting. but then i installed the latest acrobat reader and it started working. maybe the association was broken.

Comment: @Benjamin even your solution worked! tks all!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should probably state what OS you're on, but I'm going to (probably safely) assume Windows. `shell.exec` works by using Windows file permissions. If you don't have a default PDF reader set (as in right-click the PDF, select "Open with..."), then the function won't know what to do with the file.

You also probably want to use `system`, not `system2` and if you go that route (rather than `shell.exec`) be careful with your quoting in case of spaces, etc. in the file path. For example:

```
system('open "abc.pdf"')
```

Comment: ya the os is windows. I get this error. Warning message:
running command 'open "abc.pdf"' had status 63. i was working with system only. also i followed this link <https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/R_Programming/Utilities>

Comment: @ChirayuChamoli You don't have a default PDF reader configured in Windows. That makes this a Windows problem, not an R problem.

Comment: its working now. system('open abc.pdf') also works. no need to quote the file again. ya it was a windows problem.